# flash animate only one object in stage

Tags: flash, object, animation, animated

How can I animate a single object in my stage without the other objects interfering? I want to be able to click on objects and animate them. I know this can be done using a movie clip symbol, but I have now made the main animation in Scene 1 and unless there's a way to seperate this, I would have to redo ALL the animation again.

Can I just isolate animation for one object?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you already have the main animation in the scene 1 and want to separate one single object from it, you can always right-click on what do you want to separate and select "create Movie clip"

if the object spans across multiple frames, you can copy all the frames where the object is located, go to the library (F11 i think), then paste all the frames and modify them to your needs

if you want to place this animation to the main scene afterwards, just drag and drop the object from the library to the main stage, but do not forget to create a new layer for it, as someone already suggested

Comment: I found a similar approach in the end from the adobe flash help website. Allowing me to select the frames over multiple layers and then right click and select "Copy frames". I then created a new symbol ("Insert" > "New Symbol..") and pasted the frames into the new symbol. I could the drag the new symbol from library into my scene.

Answer (score 0):

Use different layers for each object.